# Getting stuck with a few things with this code

Tags: c#, api-eveonline

Greeting. I am new to coding so these problems I am facing might be quite easy for some of you. I am trying to make a simple tool that takes an exported file and read the price data in the file. but first I need to be able to import the file that is currently in \Marketlogs. All of the files are .txt.  I have gotten it to work off a set name but I have not found a way to import an unknown name. here is an example of a file name it might pull "Esoteria-Liquid Ozone-2019.05.04 015804"

I have been following along with IAmTimCorey youtube videos for the basic idea how to read the files but he is using a fixed file name for his videos

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cST5TT3OFyg&list=PLsBhi5lzz1f2-AbhurnGazN68UgG4dVwt&index=1

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yClSNQdVD7g&list=PLsBhi5lzz1f2-AbhurnGazN68UgG4dVwt&index=2

````
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;


namespace Eve_market
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /// MarketLog
            // opens a file from MarketLogs 
         ```   string filePath = @"E:\Users\Hamilton Norris\Documents\EVE\logs\Marketlogs\"; ```
            // converts file to a  readable csv from text with filteable deta
            List<MarketLog> log = new List<MarketLog>();

            List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] enteries = line.Split(',');

                MarketLog newMarketLog = new MarketLog();

                newMarketLog.Price = enteries[0];
                newMarketLog.VolReamining = enteries[1];
                newMarketLog.TypeID = enteries[2];
                newMarketLog.Range = enteries[3];
                newMarketLog.OrderID = enteries[4];
                newMarketLog.VolEntered = enteries[5];
                newMarketLog.MinVolume = enteries[6];
                newMarketLog.Bid = enteries[7]; // False = sell order  true = buy order
                newMarketLog.IssueDate = enteries[8];
                newMarketLog.Bidurationd = enteries[9];
                newMarketLog.StationID = enteries[10];
                newMarketLog.RegionID = enteries[11];
                newMarketLog.SolarSystemID = enteries[12];
                newMarketLog.Jumps = enteries[13]; //  0 = same system

                log.Add(newMarketLog);
            }

            foreach (var MarketLog in log)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{ MarketLog.Price } {MarketLog.VolReamining } {MarketLog.Bid} ");

            }


            // MarketLog End

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }
}
````

Comment: http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-files-from-directory/

Comment: I have updated line 19 to follow the link above.

new 19

string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\Users\Hamilton Norris\Documents\EVE\logs\Marketlogs\", "*.txt");

Now the filepaths in line 24 is not linking to 19 and if I remove the string[] it relinks but brakes the directory.GetfFiles

Comment: GetFiles returns a collection of files. You'll need to loop through each of them to process each file individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following code: (get the directory and then get the files having matching file pattern. Then load one by one and use your code as usual to read files)

```
 var fileNamePattern = "*.txt";
 var dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
 IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo> files = dir.GetFileSystemInfos(fileNamePattern);
 files
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(f=>        
    {
       //Load each file using File system Info:
       List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(f.FullName).ToList();
       //............
    });
```

Comment: I got it to work. I did have to change files to file